How does $m$ fit into the equation for weight?
I know part of the answer to this question because I know the equation, $W=mg$, and I know what $g$ signifies, which is the acceleration due to gravity. This acceleration is always the same on Earth because inertia and gravitational force balance out, right? However, I am confused how mass fits into the equation, as I thought that it was already covered in the variable $g$. What I mean by this is, I thought gravitational acceleration had to do with mass and gravitational pull (which is why its always the same), so how does mass $m$ fit into the equation again?

I'm sorry if this question seems basic but I am in middle school and we are learning this kind of stuff in class.

“Inertia and gravitational force balance out” is a nonsensical sentence. The acceleration due to gravity is due strictly to the masses of the bodies that are attracting one another. In the case of the surface of the earth earth, the gravitational acceleration is always the constant $g$, but gravitational force will also vary with distance between the bodies.

I think what I meant by that sentence is the reason why g is constant on Earth. You would think objects with more mass would fall faster because they have a greater attraction to Earth, as mass and gravitational force are proportional, but larger objects also have more inertia, which I think means that they fall at the same rate as objects with less mass.

The rate of falling is not affected by inertia in any way whatsoever. The reason different objects fall is due to gravity. Their acceleration is identical, so if dropped from rest their velocities agree. The reason that there will be discrepancies in practice is due to air resistance.

Without air resistance, wouldn't that mean that if it was just gravitational force acting on the objects, the object that is larger would fall faster?

@MattHanson Gravitational acceleration also depends on distance between bodies : $$ \mathbf {g} =-{GM \over r^{2}}\mathbf {\hat {r}} .$$ Also Earth is not an ideal sphere, but irregularly shaped ellipsoid, so $g$ varies also along Earth surface.

Apollo 15 footage, relevant https://youtu.be/ldSkYpqiX1s

Just equate F=ma=mg, and you will understand that acceleration alone has nothing to do with force, i.e. it has to be scaled by object mass to get force acting upon object. And weight IS force.

What you are trying to understand is very fundamental.  That does not mean it's easy.  It means it's down at the heart of how we think about motion.  I have found such fundamentals are hard to explain directly, but I think they make more sense when we consider the history of how people discovered these relationships.

You would think objects with more mass would fall faster ...

Before we had Newton's laws, Galileo determined that all objects fall at the same rate.  Well, almost.  They would fall at the same rate if there was no air resistance.  And then he demonstrated it.  So while you would think heavier objects would fall faster, he demonstrated that simply isn't true.  The idea that heavy objects fall faster is the theory Aristotle put forth in the ancient Greek era, and he was one smart cookie!  But he was wrong.  Galileo demonstrated that our very natural assumptions about how the world works isn't accurate.  One has two choices here.  One can simply believe that they fall at the same rate because one is told this, or one can go out and drop a few objects of various weights and confirm that indeed Galileo was right.
Feel free to pause here and go do whatever you feel necessary to convince yourself of this truth.  A very important part of the scientific process is verification.  Nothing is ever blindly trusted in science (although sometimes it will seem like we get really close to blind trust, especially when it comes to learning the fundamentals).
Now we can introduce Newton.  Newton defined the three laws which nowadays we say describe almost all motion (at a later time, you can learn about the quantum mechanics of the astonishingly small or the relativity of the astonishingly fast.  Everything in between is described by Newton's laws).
One of those laws, Newtons second law, is written as $F=ma$.  This is going to be the origin of the $W=mg$ that you are working with, but we will need to go through a few steps to get there.
As what I think is an important aside, I will point out that $a$, which stands for acceleration, is something new from Newton's laws.  Newton and another scientist, Leibniz, invented a new branch of mathematics we call calculus  (they called it the calculus of infinitesimals).  You may learn calculus in high school or college, depending on what degree you pursue.  If you pursue a science, technology, engineering, or mathematics degree (STEM), you'll definitely learn about that mathematics.  In the comments you mention you are in middle school.  At your stage of learning, I'd say the key takeaway is that they use this calculus to define "acceleration" precisely enough to be able to handle the concept in all cases.  You will learn some of the easier special cases along the way (such as free fall), but the real strength of Newton's laws is that they work in all cases, not just the easy ones.
The brilliance of Newton's laws is that he identified this new concept, "force," such that the sum of all of the forces acting on an object is proportional to the acceleration of that object.  We can write that as $F\propto a$, and sometimes I will write it as $\Sigma F \propto a$ to make it really clear that we are adding up all of the forces in this proportionality.
One thing you will learn in mathematics is that it's always possible to turn a proportionality into an equality by adding a constant of proportionality.  So we can always turn $F\propto a$ into $F=ka$ where $k$ is some constant.  Newton called the constant of proportionality in this particular equation "mass" and we use the letter $m$ instead of $k$.  $F=ma$.
Yay!  If you've gotten this far, you've gotten through the really hard parts.  The fact that we can make these "forces" that are proportional to accelerations is the really hard part.  It's especially hard because your teacher is statistically likely to be teaching you that these "forces" are just part of reality.  Personally, I find it very helpful to realize that some of the brilliance of Newton's laws is the invention of the concept of "forces" and defining them well enough to describe motion.
Now we can get back to Galileo.  Galileo identified that objects fall at the same rate.  Newton, with his newfound calculus, was able to show that objects accelerate towards the ground at the same rate.  Gravity is a force applied on every object, and we observe (thanks to Galileo and subsequent scientists) that they accelerate at the same rate when falling.  We give this acceleration the letter $g$, because it's important enough to earn a letter of its own.
So, while falling, we can say $F=mg=ma$, or $\Sigma F=mg=ma$ if we want to be very clear that it's the sum of forces, but in free-fall there's only one force: gravity (actually 2 forces, the other being drag, but we usually design the experiments such that drag is vanishingly unimportant).  When not falling (such as when one is stable on the ground), we can still say there is a force of gravity, equal to $mg$, as that's the force that accelerates objects in free fall.  However, there will be some force opposing it, such as the force of the ground pushing up on the object.
So now we can finally get to $W=mg$.  We define the weight of an object to be:

... the force acting on the object due to acceleration or gravity.

Note this is not the total acceleration of the object, due to all forces.  It's only the effect of gravity.
So this hopefully provides some clarity.  All objects fall at the same rate, $g$, regardless of mass, so $g$ does not account for the mass.  You have to multiply by $m$ to get the force of gravity, which is the definition of "weight."
Now you mention the balance of inertia and gravitational force.  This does not factor into the question you are looking at.  However, it is indeed a thing, so it's good to know that if you search for it, you will find answers.  Another one of Newton's laws is his law of universal gravitation, $F=\frac {GMm}{r^2}$, where $M$ and $m$ are the masses of any two objects, $r$ is the distance between them, and $G$ is the "universal gravitation constant."  The strange balance is that the mass $m$ that we see here and the mass $m$ in $F=ma$ are the same.  For some reason, objects that have a high inertial mass (are hard to accelerate) have a high gravitational attraction to other objects, and objects with low inertial mass (easy to accelerate) have low gravitational attraction.  This is indeed a peculiarity that fluxoms scientists.  But it does not play a part in the particular questions you are asking.

There are two masses involved in weight. The mass of Earth, let's call it $M$, and the mass $m$ of the object that you have in mind. The acceleration at the surface of Earth is $g=GM/R^2$ so that the total law of attraction reads $mg=GMm/R^2$.
Additional subtleties are that Earth is not a perfect sphere, that its mass shows variations and that the centrifugal force also contributes a little. As a result $g$ shows some variation depending on latitude and on location.
An extreme location is in the Indian Ocean, where gravity is so low that the sea level is 100 meters lower than average.

'The sea level dips by over 328 feet (100 meters) in a "gravity hole" first discovered in 1948. Today, scientists hypothesize that the hole in the Indian Ocean was shaped by plumes of magma coming from deep inside the planet, according to a new study.'
https://edition.cnn.com/2023/07/24/world/gravity-hole-geoid-low-indian-ocean-scn/index.html

@PM2Ring You got me.

See, the main fallacy here is equating weight with acceleration. They are two different things. Weight refers to force, not acceleration and so must depend on mass.
Now coming to the other misconception, weight is not universal. $W=mg$ is only when it is at rest with respect to the surface of the earth. A body is under a force in earth's gravity $$\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{F_g}-\mathbf{R}$$
where $\mathbf{R}$ is the reaction to the mass imparted by the surface on which it is resting and $\mathbf{F_g}$, is the force imparted by the mass on that surface. Now, $\mathbf{R}$ can change depending on the situation. Masses don't have any inherent weight. It is only when we measure them using something like a spring balance, that there is weight, $\mathbf{R}$ being the reaction of the spring to balance out the gravity. It might also happen, like in a lift or an airplane landing/taking off, that they don't 'balance' out, and the spring balance will give a different reading because what it shows is the $R$ and not the actual rest weight.
Its important to distinguish between these two concepts and think of weight as more of a measuring construct. It has nothing to do with the actual mass, because although it depends on it, it will vary depending on the situation in which it is measured.

I shall explain in simple terms.
Newton's second law states that "At any instant of time, the net force on a body is equal to the body's acceleration multiplied by its mass or, equivalently, the rate at which the body's momentum is changing with time."
And Newton gives the formula F=ma to illustrate this formula.
We know that weight is a force. Thus we can represent weight as W. So,
W=ma
But the acceleration upon an object on earth is gravity itself. So,
W=mg
Thus mass is present in the formula. Hope this answers your question.

The relation you gave $W = mg$ gives you the force of an object of mass $m$ attracted to the earth with acceleration $g$. Every object no matter their mass is falling at the same rate, or with the same acceleration towards the center of the earth (assuming no friction, otherwise a feather falls 'slower' than a ball of steel because of air friction).
What you can picture, is that if you drop two objects, one with a mass $m_1 = 1kg$ and the other with $m_2 = 2000kg$, they will both fall at the same rate, but the heavier ball will have a much stronger impact on the ground than the $1kg$ ball.
Grasping the concept of force and energy is not easy. If you ever travelled by car, and watched a truck pass you, with the same speed or slightly faster, have you ever felt a pressure on you? like you could 'feel' that truck passing by but not the other cars? Well the truck is much heavier than a small car, and the kinetic energy writes $E = 1/2 m v^2$, and here you have again the mass of the object which increases with the energy.
Don't mistake the force of an object which varies with its mass most of the time, and the acceleration which can be constants. In the case of gravitational forces, both object attract one another. When you fall down the earth, the earth also falls down to you. But you are a tiny speck for our planet so the earth won't move drastically unlike you if you are on top of Mont Everest.

$g$ includes the Earth's mass, but not your mass. Any object will free-fall with an acceleration of $g$ - not just you but also a person with double as much mass as you. Clearly, the mass of the falling object is not covered within $g$.
Have a look at Newton's law of gravitation:
$$F_g=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}.$$
$G$ is the universal gravitational constant, a constant of nature. $M$ and $m$ are the masses of two objects that feel gravitational attraction, so $M$ will be the mass of Earth. $r$ is the distance between them, which essentially is always constant for us here on Earth (the distnace to Earth's centre is constant to all practical purposes unless you fly very, very, very high up).
When calculating the gravitational force on objects that we deal with here on Earth - which is what we refer to as weight - then instead of using Newton's law of gravitation in full every time, we can just bundle all the constant together into one term:
$$g=GM/r^2.$$
Here on Earth's surface this term turns out to have the value $g=9.8\,\mathrm{m/s^2},$ but on the Moon's surface it would be $g=1.6\,\mathrm{m/s^2},$ and so on. We call it the gravitational acceleration.
So, just think of $g$ as a bundle of several other properties from the gravitation formula - if those properties happen to be close-to constant for a particular scenario, then the value of $g$ will be constant as well, and then we don't have to recalculate it all the time.

Use Einstein's equivalence principle to equate gravity with acceleration.

This means that the weight $W$ must equal to the force needed to accelerate the body with acceleration magnitude $g$
$$ W = F = m g $$
If you consider the body as consisting of many small masses, each with value $m_i$, then the force of gravity acting on each small mass is $W_i = m_i g$ then the total force applied on the body is
$$ W = \sum_i W_i = \sum_i m_i g = \left( \sum_i m_i \right) g = m g $$ which is only possible if every particle in the body feels the same acceleration $g$.
